# How can I trigger a type error in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, compile-time

Let's suppose I have a type

```
data F a = A a | B
```

I implement the function `f :: F a -> F a -> F a` like this:

```
f (A x) B = A x
f B (A _) = B
f (A _) (A x) = A x
```

However no such thing as `f B B` it's logically impossible, so I want:

```
f B B = GENERATE_HASKELL_COMPILE_ERROR
```

which is not working of course. Omitting definition or using `f B B = undefined` is not a solution, because it generates runtime exception. I'd like to get a compile time type error.

The compiler has all the information, it should be able to deduce I made a logic error. If say I declare `let z = f (f B (A 1)) B` that should be an immediate compile time error and not some runtime exception which can hide in my code for years.

I have found some info about contracts but I do not know how to use them here, and I'm curious if there is any standard way to do this in Haskell.

---

EDIT: it's turned out, what I was trying to do is called dependent type which is not fully supported in Haskell (yet). Nevertheless it's possible to generate type error using index types and several extensions. David Young's solution seems to be more straightforward approach while Jon Purdy is using type operators creatively. I accept the first but I like both.

Comment: Values can't cause type errors in Haskell because values and types do not interact. What you are asking for is known as *dependent typing*, which Haskell does not have (at least, not enough to do what you are asking).

Comment: Thanks @ReinHenrichs I indeed found some papers about dependent typing but I can't say I understood it well enough to decide whether it can be used in my case or not.

Comment: It certainly could be, just not with Haskell. You might be interested in the book _Type-Driven Development with Idris_ for a pragmatic introduction to dependent types.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs You can sometimes get a surprising amount of mileage out of the level of dependent type support Haskell has already. Possibly *just* enough to get this example working (depending on how the actual problem looks, at least). The problem, as written, looks like it could involve a slight extension of the ["phantom types as 'validation' tagging"](https://wiki.haskell.org/Phantom_type) thing (just with multiple valid combinations, instead of just one). It does depend a bit on how this function is to be used, though (and the level of code complexity you're ok with).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is possible with some type tricks, but whether or not its worth it depends on what you're doing (incidentally, you should provide some more context so we can help determine how much type machinery seems like it is worth using).

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}

import Data.Constraint

data AType
data BType

data F x y where
  A :: a -> F AType a
  B ::      F BType a

type family ValidCombo x y :: Constraint where
  ValidCombo BType ty2 = ty2 ~ AType
  ValidCombo ty1   ty2 = ()

f :: ValidCombo ty1 ty2 => F ty1 a -> F ty2 a -> F ty1 a
f (A x) B     = A x
f B     (A _) = B
f (A _) (A x) = A x
```

At compile time, it is both impossible to make a definition `f B B = ...` and it is impossible to try to call it like `f B B`. Your example `let z = f (f B (A 1)) B` will not type check (although more complex examples can run into issues).

The first thing that was done is I've added an extra argument to the `F` type constructor. This is a type index (there are no values of that type in anywhere, it is just a type level marker). I've created two different empty types (`AType` and `BType`) to use as phantom type arguments to `F`.

The type family `ValidCombo` acts as a function at the type level (notice that the definition is very similar to how a typical Haskell value-level function is defined, but with types instead of values). `()` is an empty constraint that never causes a type error (because an empty constraint is always, trivially, satisfied). At a type level, `a ~ b` constrains `a` and `b` to be the same type (`~` is type-level equality) and will give an error if they are not the same type. It is roughly analogous to value-level code that looks like this (using your original `F` type), but at a type-level:

```
data Tag = ATag | BTag
  deriving Eq

getTag :: F a -> Tag
getTag (A _) = ATag
getTag B     = BTag

validCombo :: F a -> F a -> Bool
validCombo B tag2 = (getTag tag2) == ATag
validCombo _ _    = True
```

(this could be reduced, but I've left the "tag checking" and explicit equality in for a more clear comparison.)

You can go a little bit further with `DataKinds` to require the first type argument of `F` to either be `AType` or `BType`, but I don't want to add too much extra stuff (this is discussed a bit in the comments).

All that said, in many cases, the `Maybe` solution that @DirkyJerky has provided is the way to go (due to the added complexity of the type-level manipulations).

Sometimes this type-level technique is not even fully possible in Haskell at the moment (it potentially works on the example you've provided, but it depends on how it is going to be used), but you will need to provide more information for us to determine that.

Comment: Interesting. I need some time to grok what you did above. I do not want to do anything particular. I just wanted to know if it is possible to do or not. I know I could use Maybe. Both Dependent Types suggested by Rein Heinrich and your above solution are promising.

Comment: @goteguru Well, this technically is using dependent types (since there are types depending on values). Haskell doesn't have much support for this, as Rein Henrichs said, but it has a little bit. There is a plan to add more dependent type support to Haskell. You can let me know if you have any questions. This answer might be throwing a lot of things at once.

Comment: Your `ValidCombo` type family can be rejiggered to reduce (just about) whenever possible if you use `DataKinds`, `data T = AType | BType`. Indeed, it can be written as an *open* type family. It has to be written in a somewhat strange way to satisfy the rules, but it works: `type family ValidCombo (x :: T) (y :: T) :: Constraint; type instance ValidCombo 'BType t2 = t2 ~ 'AType; type instance ValidCombo t1 'BType = t1 ~ 'AType; type instance ValidCombo 'AType _ = 'AType ~ 'AType; type instance ValidCombo _ 'AType = 'AType ~ 'AType`

Comment: Whether this is written as an open or closed type family, it will reduce as soon as GHC identifies *either* argument. The closed kind is only important if you care about the type family reducing when passed something *other* than `AType` or `BType`, which I guess you don't....

Comment: @dfeuer That is true. That is what I meant by "You can go a little bit further with `ConstraintKinds` [...]" (although I got the extension name wrong. I'll change that to `DataKinds` now), but I didn't want to throw too many extra concepts in this all at once so I just made a side note. It is good that you fill in some of the details though. Maybe I should add a section at the end. Also I wasn't aware it would work as an open type family, I assumed it had to be closed. That's interesting (especially the way you implement it).

Comment: The whole special rule for compatibility of overlapping type family instances is very weird, but it works out nicely in this case. GHC sees, for example, that if `ValidCombo 'BType t2` matches and `ValidCombo t1 'AType` matches, then `t2` is `AType`, and therefore `t2 ~ 'AType` unifies with `'AType ~ 'AType`, so all is well. There was no flexibility in the peculiar way I expressed the trivial constraint.

Comment: To be very pedantic: there are no dependent types here (Haskell doesn't yet support dependent types); the first type argument to `F` is not a phantom type (if it were, a function `F x a -> F y a` would exist); and this `F` is not the same `F` as the one in the OP (to recover the original `F`, you must write `exists i . F i x`).

Comment: @user2407038 Haskell does have minor support for dependent types. The definition of a dependent type, I believe, is a type depending on a value. That is what is happening with these two constructors. Incidentally, this why a function `F x a -> F y a` cannot be constructed (Also, I was not familiar with this requirement of a phantom type, several examples I've seen contradict that). Also, it seems possible to me to recover the original `F` without anything fancy (calling the original `F'` with constructors `A'` and `B'`): `recoverF' :: F x a -> F' a; recoverF' (A a) = A' a; recoverF' B = B'`.

Comment: @DavidYoung You have confused actual dependent typing and faking dependent typing (which is why I said "very pedantic"). In the context of a GADT, a parameter is not phantom if it is used as an index (ADTs cannot have indices anyways). Phantom type parameters represent precisely no information at runtime (which is patently not the case for an index). When I say "the same", I mean isomorphic; `recoverF'` has no inverse (indeed, there is no sensible type one could even assign to a function which is a candidate to be an inverse for `recoverF'` - you would have to create the index by some magic..)

Comment: @user2407038 I've never claimed Haskell has "actual" dependent typing. I claimed it has a limited subset (the difference between that and "faking" is just naming, I'd say). It looks like I was mistaken about phantom types. I forgot that the defining connection was to runtime information. As far as the `recoverF'` inverse goes: that is true. [You can get around that to some extent, though](https://gist.github.com/roboguy13/22f4912431221a1e8375fd62410b6140). There is also the [`dependent-sum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dependent-sum) package that is somewhat along these lines.

Comment: @user2407038 (I do hope we do get real sigma types in Haskell soon, though. [I was sort of trying "fake it" a couple years ago](https://github.com/roboguy13/natural-constructions). I know they're working on real dependent types, but I haven't looked through the details yet.)

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, the "Haskell way" of doing this would not be throwing an runtime error , but instead returning a `Maybe F`

Change the signature of `f` to be `f :: F a -> F a -> Maybe (F a)`,
and add another type catch:

```
f (A x) B = Just $ A x
f B (A _) = Just $ B
f (A _) (A x) = Just $ A x
f B B = Nothing
```

---

> The compiler has all the information

No the compiler does not have all the information.

How about, what if the user of your program decided what was input to the `f` function, and they chose two `B` data types? What would happen then? You can't throw a compile error after a program has been compiled.

Comment: Of course the compiler can't deduce user input (since it's impure) that's what exceptions are for. But it definitely could do this all in my pure code.

Comment: @goteguru: no, that is still an undecidable problem, since for the program can get stuck into an infinite loop. See the [emptiness problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/69868/emptiness-problem).

Comment: Your program can stuck into an infinite loop even if it typechecks. I'm not asking for proof of correctness, I just want to generate a compile error at certain illegal cases.

Comment: @goteguru: no, it is a common misconception that Haskells typesystem is Turing complete. It is not. Some *extensions* make it Turing complete, but the default one is quite simple.

Comment: @goteguru You still run into a fundamental problem: There are cases where you won't be able to "prove" to the compiler that something will be an `A ...`. For example, you could have an `unknown :: F a` that will give you back an `A "Eureka!"` if some unproven (or even undecidable!) mathematical conjecture is true and a `B` if it is false. Whether or not this causes an actual issue, though, somewhat depends on the broader context.

Comment: wow, you are right @DavidYoung . I've never thought about that. Thanks both of you.

Comment: While certainly nice haskeller style (and I often use it), I can't accept this as solution, because I still would have to check Nothing in runtime and that still would be a "runtime error".

Comment: @goteguru Not necessarily a runtime error. You can pattern match on a `Maybe`. You can also `fmap` over it (since it's a `Functor`) and it's also an `Applicative`, a `Monad` and an [`Alternative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative), so you can combine `Maybe`s together in a number of ways (and often avoid having to pattern match on them in the first place, eliminating all potential runtime errors related to the `Maybe`).

Comment: @DavidYoung I can't understand. It's clear I can use Maybe in Applicative style and as a Monad, but that won't save me from my own errors. It will generate a Nothing where I certainly do not want Nothing being generated. The main goal here was to warn me (preferably fail) immediately in compile time, if I'm mistakenly combining items in my code which logically cannot be combined. It would be a countermeasure in some library against programmer's errors and not some input validation (where Maybe certainly a good idea).

Answer (score 2):

Here’s another solution with type families, which you may find simpler since it just relies on Boolean logic.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators #-}

data F x a where
  A :: a -> F 'True a
  B :: F 'False a

f
  :: ((x || y) ~ 'True)
  => F x a
  -> F y a
  -> F (x || Not y) a

f (A a) B = A a
f B (A _) = B
f (A _) (A a) = A a

----

type family Not a where
  Not 'True = 'False
  Not 'False = 'True

type family a || b where
  'True || 'True = 'True  -- *
  'True || b = 'True
  a || 'True = 'True
  a || b = 'False
```

* This case isn’t necessary, but I included it for completeness.

Now it’s a type error to:

- Return `B` where `A` is expected, or vice versa
- Include the case for `f B B` (“inaccessible code”)
- Call `f B B`, even indirectly with something like `f (f B (A 1)) B`

Comment: Hah clever! :)  But it's targeting my particular example isn't it? Now if I change the declaration to `f (A _) (A a) = B` I had to introduce another  type operator `^|` and implement some sort of type level XOR (in order to define result type of `f`). Am I right?  BTW Is it possible to derive instances despite using TypeOperators? deriving(Show) throws an error now :-(

Comment: @goteguru: Yeah, you’d need to change it to enforce different things, but the type-level logic is reusable. You don’t need to use `TypeOperators`—you could name them `Or`, `Xor`, `And`, `Implies`, etc. The error you see is probably because of `GADTs`, not `TypeOperators`—it should say “Possible fix: use a standalone deriving declaration instead”, which you can do by enabling `{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}` and writing `deriving instance (Show a) => Show (F x a)`. Basically GHC just needs more information from you (the `Show a` constraint) to be able to derive an instance for a GADT.

Comment: FYI: the best version of `||` I was able to come up with (from the perspective of getting it to reduce whenever possible) was this: `type family a || b where 'True || _ = 'True; _ || 'True = 'True; 'False || y = y; x || 'False = x; x || x = x`. I have the feeling this might be the best possible, but I don't know how one would prove such a thing.

Comment: And it turns out that's the very definition used in `Data.Type.Bool`!

Comment: @dfeuer is it possible to use wildcards ( `_` ) at type level? If I remember well, it threw error for me.

Comment: yes the error was because of GADTs. There were several new concepts for me, I was not able to identify the exact source of the problem. Thx @JonPurdy